# How can I control a navigational controller when I press the back button?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm having trouble controlling some variables on my view controller with my navigational controller.  So when I press the back button I want to run a method(function) on that view controller before it goes to the previous view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either define a custom action for the back button, run your code, and then call `[UINavigationController popViewController:animated:]`, or you can set your code in `-viewWillDisappear:` if that's appropriate for what you're doing.

Comment: i tried to put my code in viewWillDisappear and it doesn't fix the error i'm having.  I'll spend a few more minutes figuring out how to access the back button

Comment: I'm not sure you can access the back button itself, you'd have to define your own button and set up a method for it to point to which then calls the pop function of the navigation controller when you're done. is `viewWillDisappear` even being called? Maybe something weird is going on.

Comment: sometimes.  When i press the back button it actually works and return to the previous view controller but when i repeat the same steps i keep getting thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i return to the previous view controller.  It's very weird.  viewWillDisappear is being called, i tested it with a nslog.

Comment: found out what it was.  Thanks for your help something small in my code was doing something wrong.  Thanks all the same.